# How to THROW exception in inner transaction without ending SQL Server stored procedure execution?

Tags: sql-server, exception, stored-procedures, transactions, throw

My objective is to throw an exception back to the caller but continue execution of the `SQL Server` stored procedure. So, in essence, what I'm trying to accomplish is a `try..catch..finally block`, even though SQL Server has no concept of a try..catch..finally block, to my knowledge.

I have a sample `stored procedure` to illustrate. It's just an example I came up with off the top of my head, so please don't pay too much attention to the table schema. Hopefully, you understand the gist of what I'm trying to carry out here. Anyway, the stored proc contains an `explicit transaction` that throws an `exception` within the `catch block`. There's further execution past the try..catch block but it's never executed, if `THROW` is executed. From what I understand, at least in SQL Server, THROW cannot distinguish between inner and outer transactions or nested transactions.

In this stored procedure, I have two tables: *Tbl1* and *Tbl2*. *Tbl1* has a `primary key` on *Tbl1.ID*. *Tbl2* has a `foreign key` on *EmpFK* that maps to *Tbl1.ID*. *EmpID* has a unique constraint. No duplicate records can be inserted into *Tbl1*. Both *Tbl1* and *Tbl2* have primary key on *ID* and employ identity increment for auto-insertion. The stored proc has three input parameters, one of which is *employeeID*.

Within the inner transaction, a record is inserted in *Tbl1* -- a new employee ID is added. If it fails, the idea is the transaction should gracefully error out but the stored proc should still continue running until completion. Whether table insert succeeds or fails, *EmpID* will be employed later to fill in *EmpFk*.

After the try..catch block, I perform a lookup of *Tbl1.ID*, via the *employeeID* parameter that's passed into the stored proc. Then, I insert a record into TBl2; *Tbl1.ID* is the value for *Tbl2.EmpFK*.

(And you might be asking "why use such a schema? Why not combine into one table with such a small dataset?" Again, this is just an example. It doesn't have to be employees. You can pick anything. It's just a widget. Imagine *Tbl1* may contain a very, very large data set. What's set in stone is there are two tables which have a primary key / foreign key relationship.)

Here's the sample data set:

```
Tbl1
ID EmpID
1  AAA123
2  AAB123
3  AAC123

Tbl2
ID Role        Location EmpFK
1  Junior      NW       1
2  Senior      NW       2
3  Manager     NE       2
4  Sr Manager  SE       3
5  Director    SW       3
```

Here's the sample stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TestProc]

    @employeeID VARCHAR(10)
    ,@role VARCHAR(50)
    ,@location VARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @employeeFK INT;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION MYTRAN;

            INSERT [Tbl1] (
                [EmpID]
            )
            VALUES (
                @employeeID
            );

        COMMIT TRANSACTION MYTRAN;
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MYTRAN;

        END;

        THROW; -- Raises exception, exiting stored procedure

    END CATCH;

    SELECT
        @employeeFK = [ID]
    FROM
        [Tbl1]
    WHERE
        [EmpID] = @employeeID;

    INSERT [Tbl2] (
        [Role]
        ,[Location]
        ,[EmpFK]
    )
    VALUES (
        @role
        ,@location
        ,@employeeFK
    );

END;
```

So, again, I still want to return the error to the caller to, i.e. log the error, but I don't wish for it to stop stored procedure execution cold in its tracks. It should continue on very similarly to a try..catch..finally block. Can this be accomplished with `THROW` or I must use alternative means?

Maybe I'm mistaken but isn't `THROW` an upgraded version of `RAISERROR` and, going forward, we should employ the former for handling exceptions?

I've used `RAISERROR` in the past for these situations and it's suited me well. But `THROW` is a more simpler, elegant solution, imo, and may be better practice going forward. I'm not quite sure.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `RAISERROR` isn't deprecated, no, so you could use it to achieve this behaviour. ([DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=56ce008ef4c29fe3a93839d843aeb612) actually fails to replicate the bahaviour here, however, if you use this SQL on your own instance, you'll see 2 result sets are returned, one without an rows, and one with)

Comment: This just screams of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Larnu. Thank you. On my SQL Server instance, the exception is thrown and the second insert is never completed. To my understanding, SQL Server doesn't decipher between transactions for thrown exceptions; hence, `THROW` exits a stored proc. If that's not the case, I'll go back to the drawing board and see if I can replicate the DB Fiddle in my instance. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not quite sure why you'd say that. This is not for an interview question but I often have seen interview questions of this fashion. If i was asked in an interview this exact question, I'd be expected to answer it to the best of my knowledge. I can't reply it's an XY problem. I have to solve it. If the problem is defined as how to throw without stopping execution, that's the task at hand, then it's not an XY problem.

Comment: By what understanding do you believe that you can throw an exception up to your caller *and* continue execution? That's not how `try`/`catch`/`finally` are usually defined.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In ssc, I've logged errors in the catch block and then continued on with the rest of the code in the finally block. It doesn't have to stop program execution cold. It could if the business logic dictates it. Depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's set in stone is there are two tables which have a primary key /
>   foreign key relationship.

Using THROW in an inner transaction is not the way to do what you want.  Judging from your code, you want to insert a new employee, unless that employee already exists, and then, regardless of whether the employee already existed or not, you want to use that employee's PK/id in a second insert into a child table.

One way to do this is to split the logic.   This is psuedocode for what I mean:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(Select employee with @employeeId)
  INSERT the new employee

SELECT @employeeFK like you are doing.

INSERT into Table2 like you are doing.
```

If you still need to raise an error when an @employeeId that already exists is passed, you can put an ELSE after the IF, and populate a string variable, and at the end of the proc, if the variable was populated, then throw/raise an error.

Comment: Ahh. Great idea. Thank you. And I can still log the exception, which is most desirable. May I make use of `THROW` or only if it's inside a catch block? Otherwise, I'll stick with `RAISERROR` to handle the exception. Thanks again.